# TreePlot with centered vertexes

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I want to draw a tree plot for Euler totient function for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251459/approaching-euler-totient-for-arbitrary-n) question like the following:

[image]

I generate the EulerPhi for first 20 numbers into a list:

```
list = Map[# -> EulerPhi[#] &, Range[2, 20]]
```

Then I plot it using this:

```
TreePlot[list, Bottom, 1, VertexLabeling -> True,  DirectedEdges -> True ]
```

And the output:

[image]

But I want the layout of tree become like the above one so that numbers of form $2^n$ are centered and branches to the left or right. How can I do this?

By manually editing the graph the output looks like the following

[image]

**Updated**

I've managed to centralize the powers of $2$ but now the branches aren't placed well.

```
y = 0; coordinates = 
 Map[First[#] -> {0, y++} &, 
 Select[Prepend[list, 1 -> {0, 0}], IntegerQ[Log[2, First[#]]] &]]

{1 -> {0, 0}, 2 -> {0, 1}, 4 -> {0, 2}, 8 -> {0, 3}, 16 -> {0, 4}}
```

and using `GraphPlot`:

```
GraphPlot[list, VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True,
    VertexCoordinateRules -> coordinates]
```

[image]

Now, If the branches are placed upper than the root, then the result would be OK.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** It turns out to be easier to construct your own vertex coordinates than trying to adjust the coordinates produced by built-in options.

```
 vrtxLst = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 8, 12, 18, "{7,9,14}",
       15, 16, 10, 13, 19, 20, 17, 11};
 edgeLst = {2 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 2, 5 -> 4, 6 -> 2, "{7,9,14}" -> 6,  8 -> 4, 
   10 -> 4,  11 -> 10, 12 -> 4, 13 -> 12, 15 -> 8, 16 -> 8, 17 -> 16,
   18 -> 6,  19 -> 18, 20 -> 8};
 alignedKPartiteCoords[layersizes_List, offsett_List] :=
    Flatten[Table[N[{i - 1, j - 1}], {j, Length[layersizes]},
       {i, 1 - offsett[[j]], layersizes[[j]] - offsett[[j]]}], 1];
 layersizes = {1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 3};
 offsets = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};
 options = Sequence[ImageSize -> 350, 
    VertexStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[None], White], VertexSize -> 0.5`, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {1/2, 1/2}],
    VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[12, RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Bold, Italic],
    VertexCoordinates -> alignedKPartiteCoords[layersizes, offsets]];
 Graph[vrtxLst, edgeLst, options]
```

[image]

---

Original post:

In version 9, you can use `Graph` with `GraphLayout` option set to `{"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> {1, 1, 3, 7, 5, 3}}`.

First manually re-ordered the vertex list to match the ordering in your first image:

```
  vl = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 8, 12, 18, 7, 9, 14, 15, 16, 10, 13, 19, 20, 17, 11};
  grph1=Graph[vl, list, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10,
   GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> {1, 1, 3, 7, 5, 3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. One of requirements is that nodes of the form `2^n` form the central spine of the tree.

Answer (score 3):

## Method 1: Semi-Automatic

My suggestion would be to use semi-automatic placement rules like

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
n = 30;
list = Map[# -> EulerPhi[#] &, Range[2, n]];
RulesPow2 = Table[2^k -> {0, k}, {k, 0, 10}];
RulesOther = Table[k -> {Automatic, GraphDistance[list, k, 1]}, {k, Complement[Range[1, n], Table[2^k, {k, n}]]}]
vcr = Union[RulesPow2, RulesOther];
TreePlot[list, Top, 1, VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexCoordinateRules -> vcr, AspectRatio -> 0.6]
```

which produces

[image]

Sadly the semi-automatic placement does not work so well for some values with many long path branches, e.g. `n=20`.

## Method 2: Roll your own Algorithm

Alternatively you can write some code to automatically calculate the coordinates for you, e.g.

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]; n = 136;
list = Map[# -> EulerPhi[#] &, Range[2, n]];
rlist = Map[#[[2]] -> #[[1]] &, list];
Pow2 = Table[2^k, {k, 0, Log[2, n]}];
vcr = {}; d = Table[0, {k, n}];
DepthFirstScan[Graph[rlist], 1, "PrevisitVertex" -> Function[
vcr = Append[vcr,
  If[MemberQ[Pow2, #], # -> {0, Log[2, #]}, 
     # -> {dd = GraphDistance[list, #, 1]; 
     d[[dd]] = Max[d[[dd]], ((# /. list) /. vcr)[[1]]] + 1; 
     d[[dd]], dd}]]]];
TreePlot[list, Top, 1, VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexCoordinateRules -> vcr, AspectRatio -> 0.6]
```

You can play with this any way you like, e.g. adjust

```
DepthFirstScan[Graph[rlist], 1, "PrevisitVertex" -> Function[
vcr = Append[vcr,
  If[MemberQ[Pow2, #], # -> {0, Log[2, #]}, 
       # -> {dd = GraphDistance[list, #, 1]; 
           d[[dd]] = Max[d, ((# /. list) /. vcr)[[1]]] + 1;
           d[[dd]], dd - 0.2}]]]];
```

The latter one should give
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to sketch out how you want the graph to look, the following may be of interest. But I warn that it requires some manual input.

Imagine you sketch out something like this:

[image: layout]

So you know you are dealing with a grid with 6 levels, 7 cols).
Assuming there are no internal gaps in the grid, you could tell MMA where you want vertices placed, going column by column.

The following,

```
layout = {{6, {20, 15, 5, 3}}, {6, {17, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1}}, {6, {11, 10,
  12, 6}}, {5, {13, 18}}, {5, {19, 7}}, {4, {9}}, {4, {14}}};
```

would be understood as meaning that the leftmost column begins as the highest level (6), and, reading downwards, should place the numbers `20, 15, 5, 3`.  And so forth.  The following will assign coordinates to each vertex.

```
g[lis_]:=Module[{pos=0,f}, 
   f[{c_,r_,ns_}]:=Module[{pos=r},#-> {c,pos--}&/@ns];
   Flatten[f[Prepend[#, pos++]]&/@lis,1]]
```

Here are the original edges:

```
edges = {2 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 2, 5 -> 4, 6 -> 2, 7 -> 6, 8 -> 4, 
  9 -> 6, 10 -> 4, 11 -> 10, 12 -> 4, 13 -> 12, 14 -> 6, 15 -> 8, 
  16 -> 8, 17 -> 16, 18 -> 6, 19 -> 18, 20 -> 8};
```

This gives the plot shown above.

```
Graph[edges,DirectedEdges -> True, VertexCoordinates -> g[layout],
ImagePadding -> 20,GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram"]
```

So does this.

```
GraphPlot[edges, VertexLabeling -> True,DirectedEdges -> True, 
VertexCoordinateRules -> g[layout]]
```

Comment: Thanks @David, the manual input is possible for small values but as I wrote in the question I'm going to generate the plot for custom n maybe as large as 1000 so manual input would be impossible

Comment: In principle, this would be possible, but it would require more time than I have available at the moment.