# GraphPlot not working properly

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The code

```
e = {{Subscript["E",1,2],Subscript["E",2,3]} -> {Subscript["E",1,3]}};
v = {{Subscript["E",1,2]}, {Subscript["E",1,3]}, {Subscript["E",
    2,3]}, {Subscript["E",1,2], Subscript["E",2,3]}};
GraphPlot[Join[e, #->#& /@ v], VertexLabeling->True, 
 EdgeLabeling->False, DirectedEdges->True, SelfLoopStyle->False,
 VertexCoordinateRules -> ((#->{Length[#],Automatic})& /@ v)]
```

produces [image], but clearly my input also specifies a vertex $\{E_{1,2}\}$. Where is it?

Comment: It is under `E[2,3]`:)

Comment: Well how can I achieve that the picture includes all vertices?

Comment: You can see all if you remove your `VertexCoordinateRules`; or replace `Automatic` with some numbers of your choice.

Comment: I need `VertexCoordinateRules` and replacing `Automatic` with concrete numbers is not possible, since I have a family of large graphs, parametrized by natural numbers, and I can't insert data for each of them.

Comment: How about `VertexCoordinateRules -> Join[(# -> {Length[#], Automatic}) & /@ v, {_ -> Automatic}]]`?

Comment: Then everything is shown, but not in its right place. I have a graph, whose vertices are the k-element subsets of some set (namely a basis of a Lie algebra), and I need all the k-element sets to be drawn on the line $x=k$, so the graph looks like a chain complex.

Comment: [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48964/125) you may find useful.